# Visual Studio - Azure Functions : Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, postgresql, visual-studio, azure, function

**Visual Studio / Azure Functions / NodeJs / Postgresql / LocalHost / MacBook**

When I try to connect to my local Postgres database It works but each time I get this message in Visual Studio

[image]

My Code : **index.js**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

    const pg = require('pg');

    const config = {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'postgres',     
        password: 'myPassword',
        database: 'myDataBase',
        port: 5432
    };

    const client = new pg.Client(config);

    client.connect(err => {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log('Error : ',err)
        }
        else {
            const query = 'select * from public.user';

            client.query(query)
                .then(res => {
                    const rows = res.rows;

                    rows.map(row => {
                        console.log(`Read: ${JSON.stringify(row)}`);
                    });

                    process.exit();
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, may I know if your problem was solved ?

Comment: @HuryShen No, I'm using from Postman and I don't have the problem now

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try to disable chrome run on background or do the operation of "Debug" --> "Options" --> disable the option "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome, Edge and IE)".

[image]

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253735/visual-studio-2017-error-cannot-connect-to-runtime-process) may help with your problem.